# Select_tag error : Error messages: Category can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-select

I want to input selections and input it into micropost table. The selections is from categories table. It encounter problem of category column of micropost is blank so I suspect it cannot input data into the table micropost column of category. I search all the select, select_tag but cannot solve it... Is there anything I miss out?

```
<%= form_for @micropost do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%=h f.text_field :title %><br />

<%= f.label :content %><br />
<%=h f.text_area :content, :row => 30, :cols=> 30 %><br />

<%  @category = Category.select("category").group("category")
    cat = @category.map{|u| u.category}
%>
    <%= select_tag :category, options_for_select(cat) %>


<%= f.submit "Post" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: can you show us the associations of the models - I'm guessing Micropost has_many :categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your query you should see that parameter `category` is sent separately from `micropost` attributes because

```
<%  
  @category = Category.select("category").group("category")
  cat = @category.map{|u| u.category}
%>
<%= select_tag :category, options_for_select(cat) %>
```

generates field inside form with name `category` not `micropost[category]` to fix it you can use [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) instead

```
 <%  
   cat = Category.select( "category" ).group( "category" ).map( &:category )
 %>
 <%= select :micropost, :category, options_for_select( cat ) %>
```